# How to find the element position using helium?

Tags: automation, helium

I am new at helium automation tool, I am trying to automate google login page

Link: https://www.google.com.bd/?gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=zi5rVfScH4yfugTkv4EY

In this page I want helium to click the sign in button 
I know the syntax can be as following

```
    click("Sign in");
    click(Button("OK"));
    click(Point(200, 300));
    click(ComboBox("File type").getTopLeft().withOffset(50, 0));
```

My question is how I can use the point and comboBox option for the above sign in button.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use click function:

```py
from helium import *
click('login in')
write("your usrname", into="field name")#input field
write("your pwd", into="field name")#input field
click('login')
```

Sometimes you should verify bot check manully.